# iOS 12 cordova app: SVG as webkit-mask-image shows strange border

Tags: css, svg, webkit, background-image, ios12

I am developing an iOS app with cordova and ExtJS 6.
Some of the background-images show a strange **rectangular border** since the update to **iOS 12** (icons in red circles, in iOS 11 the icon showed correctly as "circle containing an i without rectangle"):
[Screenshot_App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1qgo.png)

This is how the icon should look: [Screenshot_Icon_Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miOmB.jpg)

I have figured out that this behaviour occurs only, when a **SVG**-file is used as background image. PNG-files are rendered as usual without the border.

This is my CSS for this element (span):
[Screenshot_CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHUxl.jpg)

```
.elementeTree .myInfo {
  -webkit-mask-image: url('./icons/information.svg');
  -webkit-mask-position: center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 20px;
  background: var(--gray_dark);
}
```

This is a screenshot of the surrounding elements: [screenshot_dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2xL4.jpg)

I cannot figure out why the border is showing, can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the span element in a link element? try `outline: none` or `-webkit-appearance: none`.. Or maybe even `border: 0`

Comment: I just inserted a screenshot of a part of the DOM to the question. Unfortunately `outline: none` and `-webkit-appearance: none` or `border: 0` do not seem to work. It seems like the rectangle is part of the SVG. I can change the color of the rectangle the same way I can change the color of the icon (`background`). Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There is no big logic in it, but this line in css fixed my issue.

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

**Css**

```
.icon {
display:block;
width:20px;
height:20px;    
-webkit-mask-position: center;
-webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-mask-size: 100% auto;

mask-position: center;
mask-repeat: no-repeat;
mask-size: 100% auto;

transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.i-user{
-webkit-mask-image: url(../images/icons/user.svg);
mask-image: url(../images/icons/user.svg);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<i class="icon i-user"/>
```

Comment: Where did you insert this line of css? In the css-config of the class which includes the svg icon (in my case: ".elementeTree .myInfo")?
I tried your suggestion but it did not fix it for me :(

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion did not fix it for me. Thanks anyways!

Comment: fixed adding transform: translate3d(0,0,0); to svg css class

Answer (score 0):

We started seeing this in our Ionic app as well after ios12 released. In our case it seems to be something related to having the icon within a scrollable parent element that has the property `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`.

When I disable that CSS rule on the scrollable element the border disappears. This of course isn't a fix since this breaks scrolling functionality but it's somewhere to start.

Comment: I changed my app to use PNG instead of SVG which solves the "border-problem". I can change back to SVG if you want me to check your answer? Anyway thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue with iOS devices when using Cordova and EXTJS 6.2 combination for our application specifically when SVG icons are set as "-webkit-mask".

Instead of using **`transform: translate3d(0,0,0)`** which sporadically worked, I tweaked it to **`transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 1px)`** on the div to which SVG was set as "-webkit-mask" which worked fluently not only on simulator but on devices as well.

Tweaking the z-axis parameter didn't hamper my implementation much but above all  the nagging unusual border issue was fixed by this approach.